# Getting ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 on Laravel Form Submit

Tags: laravel-5, form-submit, mod-security2

I am trying to submit a form in Laravel but getting this error:

ModSecurity: Access denied with code 44 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] [line "31"] [id "200002"] [msg "Multipart request body     failed strict validation:     PE 0,     BQ 0,     BW 0,     DB 0,     DA 0,     HF 0,     LF 0,     SM 0,     IQ 1,     IP 0,     IH 0,     FL 0"]

No file upload nothing, it's just simple form submit.

I tried without special chars in form data but still getting this error.

Any suggestions?

I tried submitting data w/o special chars
I tried (earlier) uploading a file w/o special chars in the file name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set Dev on Duty here.
The following line provides some hints about what has been triggered:

```
PE 0, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM 0, IQ 1, IP 0, IH 0, FL 0
```

Specifically `IQ 1`, shows that the error is `MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING` (See [modsecurity.conf-recommended rule 200003](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/blob/v3/master/modsecurity.conf-recommended#L83)).

- Even if you are not uploading a file, it seems that the request is still considered an upload of some sort, and the multipart parser tries to deal with it. Is your request containing quoting elements, like single quotes? (Interesting [related conversation](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/199))
- Also, could you provide some more details about the environment and the ModSecurity version you are using? There seems to be a misalignment between the id reported in your log and the actual message (reported rule `200002` with a message of rule `200003`), and it can be a customization of that file, or a pretty old one (Status code [44](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/commit/ab9aede2e54c01a5d92544098e186bbceb305348) has been changed about 10 years ago).